# How to get Azure Active Directory authenticated to access Azure SQL from a C# client app?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, multi-factor-authentication

So I have a C# client app UI. The UI needs to retrieve some data from Azure SQL.
My Azure SQL has an Azure Active Directory Admin set/enabled.

The users who use the UI all should have access to Azure SQL (i.e. log in to SQL Server Management Studio) via Active Directory Integrated/MFA authentication.

I would like to the authentication experience be seamless. However, prompting/challenging the user with a login prompt would be just fine as well.

The problem is that when I run the UI, i get prompted for my login. I provide my id/email address, and if I provide them in a certain way, i get the MFA process going (i get a phone call to authenticate myself).
However, upon getting authenticated, i see an immediate prompt that says the app **"...needs permission to access resources in your organization that only an admin can grant. Please ask an admin to grant permission to this app before you can use it."**

Note that I am essentially following this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/active-directory-interactive-connect-azure-sql-db).

Questions:

Is it possible to avoid this process which requires an Admin to approve?

Would it be acceptable for the UI itself to send an approval request (using the AAD Admin set under Azure SQL)?

Comment: did you use the AD admin account to access the database, which database did you access?  AD account like sql login, if you are not using admin account, you must grant the account permission to access the database.

Comment: Thanks Leon. I will try logging in using the sql admin account. But, isn't there a way to make this work? After all, I am able to login using my personal org account when i connect to the same database via SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Wondering if this is a better alternative? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51707764/azure-sql-and-aad-authentication

Comment: Please let us know have you given admin consent?

Comment: Are you still looking for any help with this question?